# Submitting ASP form from Java application

Tags: java, javascript, asp.net

I am writing a Java application that has a log in screen.  Ideally, I would like to take the user supplied data (name, password), and submit it to an ASP form that can verify their credentials.  I do not own the ASP form, I can only access the URL.  I also do not want the user to be entering their credentials straight into the web form.  They would enter their credentials into my program, and my program would put the data into the form and submit, and allow/deny the user based on the response.

Of course, the submit button on the ASP form is a POST request.  However, constructing the URL (...login?username=name&password=pass) does not work, as the form must be submitted via the button with the text boxes filled in.

I have tried two approaches:

1. Using Java's URLConnection class.  This does not seem to work because the form submitting is limited to the method I mentioned above, which is constructing the URL.
2. Using Javascript to access and edit the elements on the page.  This has not worked either, because the Javascript is being run from my program, which is not a web browser, and therefore has no access to the 'document' or 'window' commonly used.

Other potential solutions I can think of:

1. Opening a browser to the login page but not giving it focus, running a script to fill out and submit the form, parsing the response, and then closing the browser.  This would not involve the user at all, except for the input into the login page in my Java program.
2. Using a 3rd party Java library (suggestions? references to tutorials?).
3. Embedding the URL into my login screen (any help in this regard would be appreciated).

The things that cannot be changed are that my program is in Java, and that the login URL is an ASP form that hides the POST data from the URL.

Let me know if anything needs clarification.  Any help is welcome.

Comment: `...login?username=name&password=pass` - you should never do that, since the password would then be visible to anybody who intercepts that call or has access to the webserver's log files.

Comment: @Thomas Yeah I agree, I was just trying things to see what would work. It would be much better if the form could be filled out and submitted directly from my program because the web form is secure.

Comment: AFAIK you should be able to submit a POST request using `URLConnection`, just put the parameters into the request body instead of the URL (create a writer for the connection and write the parameters to it).

Comment: @Thomas Thanks -- how would I put the parameters into the request body instead of the URL? I have an OutputStreamWriter for the connection.  Currently I write the username and password to the connection, but it doesn't seem to submit anything.

Answer (score 0):

try htmlunit, although it was designed for testing it would be ideal for this. You can use it in conjunction with Selenium webdriver

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you open up your ASP form in an IFrame using javascript populate all the fields & then post it.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks -- the issue I face here is that my JS is run through my program and is not associated with a web browser.  This means that when I call document.createElement("iframe"); or something similar, I get the error: ReferenceError: "document" is not defined.

Comment: Can't you add it to client side of your page?

Comment: I don't own the page and can't add any code to it.  It's the secure login for my school, where the generic user of my program is an employee of the school and has credentials to use the school's login.  Instead of making them deal with another set of credentials, I want to let them use the ones they already have.  I want my JS to be able to access content on that page without the code itself being embedded in the page.  I'm not sure if that's even possible.

Comment: Essentially, I would like to be able to do something like var form = [site].getElement("form"), where usually one would be able to say document.getElement("form").

Answer (score 0):

Sfk is correct, i had a similar problem and manage to fill the form and submit it with [Htmlunit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) .@sfk many thanks, you put me in the right path.

So with htmlunit

```
 //for chrome simulation
 WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME_16);
 //has getting an error from [http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js with javascript on.
 webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);

 HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://yourtargetpage/Default.aspx");

//get the form by name, check page source for name
 HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("aspnetForm");
 HtmlPasswordInput inputPass =  form.getInputByName("your input password text field name");    
 HtmlTextInput userName =  form.getInputByName("your input user text field name");

 HtmlSubmitInput button=form.getInputByName("your target submit button");

 //set username and password
  userName.setText("myuser");
  inputPass.setText("mypassword");
//click the submit button and get the returned page
  HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
```

That´s it.. you got the reply page and sent the information on the fields..you can now parse the page and get the site response..